# Data is not get posted to backend through ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to post data to a php file through ajax call. But I could not get those data in my php file. It just returns the empty array when I check using var_dump($_POST). Anyone help me on this.

Here is my ajax script

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
                url: "update_user.php",
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    "type": "active"
                },
                error: function (e) {
                },
                success: function(data) {

                }
            }); 
</script>
```

In update_user.php,

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

It returns array(0) { }

Comment: Are you literally posting `type:active`?

Comment: How do you know it returns that? show us how you get it from the page.

Answer (score -1):

I think type should be POST (uppercase not lower).

```
$.ajax({
            url: "update_user.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                type: "active"
            },
            error: function (e) {
            },
            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
```